# Create multi-tenant Service Principal from powershell - New-AzADServicePrincipal is missing SignInAudience parameter

Tags: azure, azure-service-principal, azure-app-registration

I'm trying to create a service principle that will be accessible from other tenants.
I want to deploy this service principal from powershell with function New-AzADServicePrincipal.

According to the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-8.1.0 - it had parameter "SignInAudience".

Currently, when I try to set this parameter to "AzureADMultipleOrgs" I get the error:

```
New-AzADServicePrincipal : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SignInAudience'.
```

This the code that I'm using:

```
New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName test -SignInAudience "AzureADMultipleOrgs"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this is:

```
    $ServicePrincipal = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $servicePrincipalName

    Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipal.AppId -SignInAudience "AzureADMultipleOrgs"
```